# Running a systemd service as a user other than root!

Tags: systemd, services, init

I created the following service, amos.service, and it needs to run as amos (member of the amos group)

```
[Unit]
Description=AMOS Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=amos
Group=amos
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/amos
ExecStart=/usr/share/amos/amos_service.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/share/amos/amos_service.sh stop
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

all the permissions have been set on `/usr/share/amos` to `amos:amos`

the amos_service.sh is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

CUDIR=$(dirname "$0")
cd /usr/share/amos

start() {
  exec /usr/share/amos/run_amos.sh >> /var/log/amos.log 2>&1  
}

stop() {
  exec pkill java 
}

case $1 in
  start|stop) "$1" ;;
esac

cd "$CURDIR"
```

When I run the service initially without any modifications to the directories, meaning, belonging to root, and amos.service not having the User not Group parameter, everything runs great!

Once I change the directories permissions to amos:amos and add the amos.service User & Group, the serive won't work and I get the following : See attached image

[image: Error after trying to run service]

Comment: What is the difference, if any, between the success and failure cases in terms of the messages logged to /var/log/amos.log ?

Comment: Also, this configuration is odd in that `/var/log` is owned by root. I think you want to use a directory `/var/log/amos/` which you create as owned by amos.

Comment: I will create as mentioned and will log back results

Comment: This `exec pkill java` is really bad! If you have any other service using Java, oh well...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use systemd:

To show the problem use `journalctl -xe` after you started the service.

You don't need a bash script, put this in your service file:

```
ExecStart=/usr/share/amos/run_amos.sh
```

There is no need for `ExecStop`, systemd will stop all child processes. You can view the output with `journalctl -u amos.service`.

Answer (score 6):

I think you want forking instead of simple.  Simple assumes your process doesn't exit, so when it does, it calls the process dead.

You probably want to remove the amos_service.sh script and put it's functionality into the amos.service.

Comment: Will make changes as suggested...was reading about it and saw your comment.  Will log back results.

Answer (score 2):

First find your config you want to change using the following command:

```
systemctl list-unit-files
```

Then change the specific config using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full tomcat9.service
```

This will open the file in the default text editor set in the `EDITOR` environment variable.

Now add the specific user and group user service section.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe authorize `amos` user to launch services thanks to the enable-linger option?

```
loginctl enable-linger amos
```

(cf. [man loginctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html), it seems to be mandatory)