# SLES12 : How to run a process with a specific user?

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse

I want to run a process with a specific user.

On RHEL 7, I am able to this with:

```
source /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
daemon --user=myuser $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $appClassPath $MAIN_CLASS
```

How can I achieve the same behavior on SLES12? The `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` is not available on SLES12 out of the box.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363098/running-a-systemd-service-as-a-user-other-than-root

Comment: also search on`systemd user service`.  might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

SUSE wants Your to use LSB start_daemon. (https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Packaging_init_scripts).
But I'm not certain whether it will be continued in systemd times or is about to be phases out.
Of course recommended way in systemd systems is to create a systemd unit...

Otherwise use the default tools like `runuser` or `su` or even sudo which has the convenience that You can call it as any user with permissions to run that command line.
Background and detach Your program within these wrappers (or exec it). Possibly with help of nohup.
That is more standard conforming and not coupled to a deprecated init-system infrastructure.

Comment: I have created the systemd unit file. Is there a different way to specify user in systemd unit file?

Comment: Use `User=someuser` in the `[Service]` section on the unit file. These things are easy to google.

Comment: Also the question title is misleading. "Run a process as different user" does not sound like working on a systemd unit... ;-)